# Python код не видит файлов из других директорий

Tags: python, импорт

Есть код с такими путями:

```
(local dir.)/database
(local dir.)/handlers
```

Внутри обоих есть `__init__.py` с import'ами
При попытке вызвать database внутри файла handlers.py внутри второй папки, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\Bots\pizzaBot\handlers\handlers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from database.database import Pizza, Drinks
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

Файл `__init__.py` внутри database:

```
import database.database
import database.dbDef
```

Файл `__init__.py` внутри handlers:

```
import handlers.handlers
import handlers.initialize
```

Импорт файла handlers.py указан в ошибке.
В чем заключается ошибка? Почему handlers.py не видит database?
Уже пробовал:

```
import database

from database import *

from database import Drinks, Pizza
```

Comment: ищется внутри папки handlers, а в ней нет папки database

Comment: тогда каким образом сделать так, чтобы он искал в корневой папке проекта?

Comment: Чтобы видело оба пакета, нужно запускать из их общей директории, и как пакет (типа `python -m handlers.initialize`)

Comment: можешь, пожалуйста, расписать точнее, как именно это реализовать в коде?

Comment: @mIbItard, либо запускаете из командной строки примерно как я показал выше, либо добавляете пусковой модуль снаружи обоих ваших пакетов, в нем уже импортируете и запускаете то что вам нужно. В обоих этих случаях общая директория этих пакетов будет автоматически добавлена в PYTHONPATH, и "параллельный импорт" заработает